# Writing strings into three columns into a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three strings, each having 361 numbers in them. What I need to do is print the strings into three separate columns in a text file.

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Becomes,

1  1  1

2  2  2

3  3  3

4  4  4

5  5  5

Comment: If it is your homework. try to do it first and we can discuss the solution.
There are too many ways these can be done.

Comment: You say 'strings', but then you give three arrays in the question. Also, don't give such examples that can be misunderstood. Give sample arrays like [1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 23] etc. which are unique.

Comment: @digitake this is part of an ongoing script I've been trying to write to make data collection easier in my lab. It is certainly not a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Since they are all the same length, it is really simple:

```
ll = [a, b, c]
length = 361
with open("file.txt", "w") as output:
    for i in range(length):
        output.write(" ".join([str(l[i]) for l in ll]) + "\n")
```

First you put all your lists in a list for easy access. Then, for each index, you combine into a string every item in every list with that index, using space as a delimiter. I included `str()` in the line where the string is created to avoid errors due to the type of the item in the list.

Comment: `length = 361`? What? Why?

Comment: @Aran-Fey OP said "I have three strings, each having 361 numbers in them", which I interpreted as meaning that each one has 361 items.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Still, I don't see a reason to hard-code that number. Why not use `len` to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

if you can use numpy

```
A = np.array([a,c,b]).transpose()
np.savetxt('output.txt',A)
```

Comment: `numpy` is overkill for this.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` the lists together, then iterate over the resulting tuples.

```
for t in zip(a, b, c):
    print(*t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip all-list element-wise into one-list of "tuple"

```
zip(a,b,c)
```

the result will look like this: [(1,1,1), (2,2,2), ... ]
then you can "map" the result from "tuple" to "string"

```
map(lambda tup: "%s %s %s" % tup, zip(a,b,c))
```

Pythonically,

```
["%s %s %s" % tup for tup in zip(a,b,c)]
```

Now you will get a list of string. Then you can now write to file. In order to make it multilines, we need '\n' char. We can use handy "join" function to join list and separate them by newline char.

So my solution gonna be like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
with open("targetfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(["%s %s %s" % tup for tup in zip(a,b,c)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach :

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


print(list(zip(a,b,c)))
```

output:

```
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4), (5, 5, 5)]
```